# How to make Drawer Navigation page Scrollable?

Tags: android, scroll, navigation-drawer

Hi I am newbie to coding, please forgive my ignorance.

Made a fully functional swiping view with a drawer, but I would like the navigation view inside the drawer being able to scroll down to view offscreen items. I tried wraping the whole thing inside ScrollView, but then i get "DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY" while drawer layout is set "match parent" all the time, can't solve it and I don't know whether that is on the right track, please advise, thank you so much!

**swipelayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".i_SwipingLayout">

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start"
 app:headerLayout="@layout/i_header"
 app:menu="@menu/draw_menu"
 app:itemIconTint="@color/ColorDropiii"
 app:itemTextColor="@color/ColorDropi">
 </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/ColorDropi"
            android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/ColorDropi"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: Ok thanks! I changed the tags, hope it helps!

Comment: You re-added irrelevant tags; did you read the tag descriptions or the linked article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, there is no need to use a scrollview layout to include everything, I just rearrange the position of the objects within the drawer layout xml file(page which contains the drawer" so that nevigationView is below everything. Works perfectly afterwards.